# Multiple inserts with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the DB tables: `images` and `category`

Currently the only function to insert in category table  is similar to this:

```
public function add($ttitle)
{      
try
    {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO category (title) VALUES(:title)");
        $stmt->bindparam(":title",$ttitle);                 
        $stmt->execute();
        return true;

    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();  
        return false;
    }

}
```

I have a form to enter title and the possibility of inserting urls images.

By clicking on the submit the title I want to go to the category table, so far ok, images should go to the table images, an id for each image but with inner join to the id of the category.

The table `images`:

```
id_image | category_id | dir_image
```

I am not able to do this properly

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO category (title) VALUES(:ttitle)");

$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT id_image FROM images WHERE id_category = category_id ");
```

Example of the result I want:

html form

```
Category title: Test
Image1:   image1.png
Image2:   image2.png
Image3:   image3.png
Image4:   image4.png
              Submit
```

after submit

Table category:

```
 id_category | title
    1          Test
```

Table images:

```
 id_image | category_id | dir_image
    1            1         image1.png
    2            1         image2.png
    3            1         image3.png
    4            1         image4.png
```

---

**Update:**

```
public function add($ttitle,$images)
{
try {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO category (title) VALUES(:title)");
        $stmt->bindparam(":title",$ttitle);                    
        $stmt->execute();

        $lastId = $db->lastInsertId();

       $imgs = count($images);
       for ($i = 0; $i < $imgs; $i++){

       $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO images (category_id, dir_image) VALUES (:title)");
        $stmt->bindparam(":category_id",$lastId); 
        $stmt->bindparam(":dir_image",$images);
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute()

        } 



        return true;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();    
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: You keep saying inner join, I think you mean foreign key. Take a look at the `lastInsertId()` method of PDO, it returns the ID assigned when you inserted into `category`.

Comment: You can then use that ID when as `category_id` when you insert into `images`.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar I inserted details in my question, please see

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#multiexec

Comment: @YourCommonSense I'm making a mistake in for?

Comment: yes, you are. Do not use for, use foreach instead. Put prepare outside of the loop, you're losing the benefit of prepared statements

Comment: Thanks. For the update I believe that I understand  the example of your link but I can not imagine how to use foreach on the insert

Comment: It's essentially the same.

Comment: Is `$images` an array or scalar string and where does `$sql` derive? Might be helpful to show how this function is called.

Comment: @Parfait, yes $images is array (images urls coming from form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things:

1. Remove the second prepare statement inside `for` loop
2. Add binded params into the `VALUES()` of sql statement
3. Index the `$images` array with `for` loop iterator or use `foreach`

See adjusted `for` loop:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO images (category_id, dir_image) 
                            VALUES (:category_id, :dir_image)");

$stmt->bindParam(":category_id" ,$lastId); 
$stmt->bindParam(":dir_image", $image);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($images); $i++){
    $image = $images[$i];
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Alternatively with `foreach` loop *(assuming a one-dimension array)*:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO images (category_id, dir_image) 
                            VALUES (:category_id, :dir_image)");

$stmt->bindParam(":category_id", $lastId); 
$stmt->bindParam(":dir_image", $item);
foreach ($images as $item){
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @parfait, it became clear to me

Comment: It's `bindParam`, not `bindparam`.

Comment: @Gisele Because PHP is case sensitive. http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: thank you, I will correct but currently displays no errors. I figured that if there was any error, or more specifically with case sensitive error would show error messages, even activating to display errors, they do not appear if I inform bindparam